# How can I make an asynchronous interaction between two contracts?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, transactions, blockchain

How can I make an asynchronous interaction between two contracts? I have contract A and contract B.

- contract A calls contract B
- contract B obtains data from an external source
- contract B returns the data to A.

is it possible to realize the interaction between A and B through callback?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I make 'wait n seconds' statement in solidity function?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/47070/can-i-make-wait-n-seconds-statement-in-solidity-function)

Answer (score 1):

The 2nd bullet is not possible strictly from on-chain.

The asynchronous part of your system can only be an off-chain service which sends the data.

The rest of the process, as depicted in the 1st and 3rd bullets, will be synchronous of course.

Comment: can you give me an example of how B returns data to A?

Comment: @MarioRoma: When "contract A calls contract B" (your 1st bullet), immediately "contract B returns the data to A" (your 3rd bullet). By `immediately`, I mean `within the same transaction`.

Comment: the only way to make the interaction asynchronous is to use events? When contract B has obtained the data it emits an event and A makes a transaction to B to retrieve the data.Is it right?

Comment: @MarioRoma: No, that's wrong. Events are used only for recording data on the blockchain. Contracts can only emit events, they cannot read them. Events can be used only in an off-chain script/app/service. Please read the answer again. You cannot achieve an asynchronous process strictly in the on-chain. The asynchronous part of your system must be implemented in the off-chain.

Comment: I meant that a node receives the event it subscribed to and calls contract A. contract A calls contract B and retrieves the data.

Comment: @MarioRoma: An ethereum node doesn't "receive an event", and most certainly doesn't "call a contract". You need to implement an off-chain service to scan the blockchain, search for such event and call contract A accordingly.